# Pinch to Zoom using Google Maps Javascript API in Android Browser

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

Has anyone gotten pinch to zoom to work for a Google Map in the Android Browser? It works fine in Android applications and I hear it works in iPhone's Safari Browser but I'm interested in getting it to work in a web app that's viewed via the Android Browser. Currently you can pinch zoom in but the map does not redraw (i.e. it just gets larger and pixelated). You cannot pinch zoom out.

**Edit:** It seems to be different on each phone:
Evo - Problem discussed above
Epic - Pinch to zoom out works, zoom in has problem discussed above
Galaxy S - Pinch to zoom in and out both work fine

Answer (score 1):

At the current time, Google Maps API v3 (and any other JavaScript code, for that matter) cannot rely on receiving events related to pinch-to-zoom in JavaScript on Android browsers.  See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11909

If this issue is important to you, I recommend logging in, starring the issue, and leaving a good comment.

For what it's worth, I have not run across this problem in Honeycomb, which makes me at least slightly hopeful that Ice Cream Sandwich will fix this for the phones.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Android doesnt support multitoches events for javascript. It support only touchstart/mode/end events, but not gesture events so it dont support zoom in out, (for me doesnt work even on galaxy s). Maybe in the android 3.0 they will add this event to browser.